# get label name through mouse click listener in java

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to open text file if that have a name on the label text if the user click on label the file named with same label text will open.
i was tried to use mouse-clicked listener but i don't know how to get the label name.

this is the code :

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.getText());
            }
    };

    label1.addMouseListener(ml);

    label2.addMouseListener(ml);

    label3.addMouseListener(ml);
```

Comment: Try the Swing component File Chooser: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By name on the label, you meant label text? You can get text easily by

```
label.getText();
```

EDIT:

```
class CustomLabelClickListener implements MouseListener {

    String labelText;
    public void MouseLabelClickListner(String text) {
        labelText = text;
    }
...

@Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            System.out.println(label.getText())
        }
...
}
```

Add custom listener to label:

```
label1.addMouseListener(new CustomLabelClickListener(label1.getText()));
```

When clicking on label, text will be shown in console.

Comment: yeah,i know that but i am using one mouseclicked for multiple label

Comment: Could you be more specific? Maybe adding screenshot or providing code would help.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          System.out.println(label.getText());
     }
});
```

Comment: yeah,i know that but i am using one mouseclicked for multiple label